# SwiftUI Carousel scrollPosition not properly centered

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

I have a carousel made with `ScrollView` and I am trying to control/init the `.scrollPosition(id:)` from a parent view.

Here is the Custom Slider:

```
struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    private(set) var id: UUID = .init()
    var color: Color
    var title: String
    var subTitle: String
    
    static var previews: [Item] = [
        .init(color: .red, title: "World Clock", subTitle: "View the time in multiple cities around the world."),
        .init(color: .blue, title: "City Digital", subTitle: "Add a clock for a city to check the time at that location."),
        .init(color: .green, title: "City Analouge", subTitle: "Add a clock for a city to check the time at that location."),
        .init(color: .yellow, title: "Next Alarm", subTitle: "Display upcomiong alarm.")
    ]
}

struct CustomPagingSlider<Content: View, TitleContent: View, Item: RandomAccessCollection>: View where Item: MutableCollection, Item.Element: Identifiable {
    
    /// View Properties
    @Binding var activeID: UUID?
    @State var data: Item
    
    /// Customization Properties
    var showsIndicator: ScrollIndicatorVisibility = .hidden
    var showPagingControl: Bool = true
    var disablePagingInteraction: Bool = false
    var titleScrollSpeed: CGFloat = 0.6
    var pagingControlSpacing: CGFloat = 20
    var spacing: CGFloat = 10
    
    @ViewBuilder var content: (Binding<Item.Element>) -> Content
    @ViewBuilder var titleContent: (Binding<Item.Element>) -> TitleContent
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: pagingControlSpacing) {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(spacing: spacing) { // not working when using HStack
                    ForEach($data) { item in
                        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                            titleContent(item)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .visualEffect { content, geometryProxy in
                                    content
                                        .offset(x: scrollOffset(geometryProxy))
                                }
                            
                            content(item)
                        }
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollIndicators(showsIndicator)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .scrollPosition(id: $activeID)
        }
    }
    
    func scrollOffset(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        let minX = proxy.bounds(of: .scrollView)?.minX ?? 0
        
        return -minX * min(titleScrollSpeed, 1.0)
    }
}
```

In this DetailedView I will use `onChange(of: )` to do something when the `activeID` changes from the `CustomPagingSlider`.

```
struct DetailedView: View {
    
    /// View Properties
    @State var items: [Item]
    @State var activeID: UUID?
        
    /// Customization Properties
    @State private var showPagingControl: Bool = false
    @State private var disablePagingInteraction: Bool = false
    @State private var pagingSpacing: CGFloat = 20
    @State private var titleScrollSpeed: CGFloat = 0.75
    @State private var stretchContent: Bool = true
    
    init(items: [Item], activeID: UUID?) {
        self._items = State(wrappedValue: items)
        self._activeID = State(wrappedValue: activeID)
        
        if let item = self.items.first(where: { $0.id == activeID }) {
            print("DetailedView init: \(item.title)")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomPagingSlider(activeID: $activeID,
                               data: items,
                               showPagingControl: showPagingControl,
                               disablePagingInteraction: disablePagingInteraction,
                               titleScrollSpeed: titleScrollSpeed,
                               pagingControlSpacing: pagingSpacing
            ) { $item in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                    .fill(item.color.gradient)
                    .frame(width: stretchContent ? nil : 150, height: stretchContent ? 220 : 120)
            } titleContent: { $item in
                VStack(spacing: 5) {
                    Text(item.title)
                        .font(.largeTitle.bold())
                        .frame(height: 45)
                        .background(.cyan)
                    
                    Text(item.subTitle)
                        .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .frame(height: 45)
                }
            }
            .safeAreaPadding([.horizontal], 35)
            
            List {
                Toggle("Show Paging Control", isOn: $showPagingControl)
                
                Toggle("Disable Page Interaction", isOn: $disablePagingInteraction)
                
                Toggle("Stretch Content", isOn: $stretchContent)
                
                Section("Title Scroll Speed") {
                    Slider(value: $titleScrollSpeed)
                }
                
                Section("Paging Spacing") {
                    Slider(value: $pagingSpacing, in: 20...40)
                }
            }
            .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 15))
            .padding(15)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Detailed View")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

But I want to make the `CustomPagingSlider` to position on a specific item (selected from the `ContentView` when displaying the `DetailedView`, not always on the 1st item.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items: [Item] = Item.previews
    
    @State private var showDetailedView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(value: item) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                            Text(item.title)
                                .font(.largeTitle.bold())
                            
                            Text(item.subTitle)
                                .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                .frame(height: 45)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Items")
            .navigationDestination(for: Item.self) { item in
                DetailedView(items: items, activeID: item.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It does not work at all when using a `HStack` within the `CustomPagingSlider` (see comment). It works when using `LazyHStack`, but the positioning is not correctly aligned (check video). When selecting the 3rd item, the positioning is not aligned.
[enter link description here](https://streamable.com/i1dxea)

Comment: working fine for me on iPhone 15, iOS 17.0

Comment: @SPatel, have you changed anything in the above code?

Comment: I also noticed that when using LazyHStack, the horizontal ScrollView takes half of the screen as height while the list takes the other half, but when using HStack, the ScrollView only takes the necessary  height which is less than half.
Any idea why does this happen?